# Button won't center in the middle of section

Tags: html, css

I can't get .btn-calculate to centre in the middle of the section below my form. No position styling seems to have any effect. Not sure what's going wrong.

P.S I haven't made it responsive yet so it's not pretty if not viewed in a full browser, but you can see the button won't move to the centre whatever you try.

```css
/* Survery Section Start */

.survery {
    background-color: #1b262c;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.survery-h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

input: label {
    color: white;
}

input {
    text-indent: 10px;
}


.survery-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-name-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.home-phone-footer {
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.home-email-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.btn-calc {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 20rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.thebutton {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Survery Start -->
   <section class="survery">
       <div class="survery-title">
           <h1 class="survery-h1">Scrappage Payment Survey</h1>
       </div>
        <form action="">
        <div class="survery-questions">
                <div class="name-form">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="email-form">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="home-email-footer" id="input" required name="_replyto">
                </div>

                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                <div class="thebutton">
                    <a href="" class="btn-calc">Calculate Payment</a>
                
                </form>

            </div>
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could do `width: 100%` on `class="thebutton"`.

Comment: This worked. Why did this work? Thanks

Comment: You were trying to use center on a flex element, but the parent had no width, only the same width as the button. So you needed to give the parent container a width so flex would put the button at the center of that parent div.

Comment: Legend. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` to `class="thebutton"`, which will align the `anchor` element which is acting as button in centre

```css
.survery {
    background-color: #1b262c;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.survery-h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

input: label {
    color: white;
}

input {
    text-indent: 10px;
}


.survery-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-name-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.home-phone-footer {
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.home-email-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.btn-calc {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 20rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.thebutton {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="survery">
  <div class="survery-title">
    <h1 class="survery-h1">Scrappage Payment Survey</h1>
  </div>
  <form action="">
    <div class="survery-questions">
      <div class="name-form">
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>

      </div>

      <div class="phone-form">
        <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
      </div>

      <div class="email-form">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="home-email-footer" id="input" required name="_replyto">
      </div>

      <div class="phone-form">
        <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
      </div>

      <div class="name-form">
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>

      </div>

      <div class="phone-form">
        <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
      </div>

      <div class="name-form">
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>

      </div>

      <div class="phone-form">
        <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
      </div>
      <div class="thebutton">
        <a href="" class="btn-calc">Calculate Payment</a>

  </form>

  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shoudl help serve your purpose. Simply adding `width:100%` and `display:flex` to `.theButton` works.

```css
/* Survery Section Start */

.survery {
    background-color: #1b262c;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.survery-h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

input: label {
    color: white;
}

input {
    text-indent: 10px;
}


.survery-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-name-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.home-phone-footer {
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.home-email-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.btn-calc {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 20rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.thebutton {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
display: flex
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Survery Start -->
   <section class="survery">
       <div class="survery-title">
           <h1 class="survery-h1">Scrappage Payment Survey</h1>
       </div>
        <form action="">
        <div class="survery-questions">
                <div class="name-form">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="email-form">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="home-email-footer" id="input" required name="_replyto">
                </div>

                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                <div class="thebutton">
                    <a href="" class="btn-calc">Calculate Payment</a>
                
                </form>

            </div>
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this commented by justDan any difference?

Comment: I have also tried adding display:flex, for better usability, and i was in the code editing mode yet , i completed just now @RayeesAC

Comment: please look for the display:flex property clubbed with width:100% to make use of flex related attributes like justify-content etc. @TannerDolby

Comment: please look for the display:flex property clubbed with width:100% to make use of flex related attributes like justify-content etc. @RayeesAC

Comment: Can you please add difference in answer too as description. for more clarity. Thanks :)